# The view django_bookmarks.bookmarks.views.register_page didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python

The view `django_bookmarks.bookmarks.views.register_page` didn't return an HttpResponse object. How can I fix this problem?

**The code**

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.clean_data['username'],
                password=form.clean_date['password1'],
                email=form.clean_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        var = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
        })
        return render_to_response( 'registration/register.html',var
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an alternative for your "if" condition. What if `request.method` is not POST?:

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render_to_response(...)
```